# Calling a function in a separate file with parameters defined on the initial one

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following in a python file with the name: `file1.py`

```
a=1
def f(x):
  return x+a
```

Now, in another file (Let's say `file2.py`) if I import the above function,
that is:
`from file1 import f`

and then, evaluate it at a certain value, say;
`print(f(2))` gives the value `3` because, 2+a=2+1=3.
That means the code has used the value of `a` defined in `file1.py`

Also even if I have the `file2` as,

```
from file1 import f
a=10
print(f(2))
```

It still gives the same answer as before. Which means the function has used the value of `a` defined in `file1`

So my question is, whether there is a way to write the code in `file2` so that it uses the `a` defined there.
I know that I can define the function as

```
def f(x,a):
  return x+a
```

But for my case it would be really helpful, if I can leave the function only with one variable....

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much simpler solution, and without circular dependencies:

#### file1.py

```py
a = 1
def f(x):
    return a + x
```

#### main.py

```py
import file1
print(file1.f(10)) # will print 11
file1.a = 10
print(file1.f(10)) # will print 20
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `import` statements within functions. So, if you wanted to, you could use this in `file1.py`:

```
a=1
def f(x):
  from file2 import a
  return x+a
```

In this case, the imported `a` would override the previously defined `a`, causing its value to be set to 10. To avoid this, you could use something like this:

```
a=1
def f(x):
  from file2 import a as b
  return x+b
```

While this method does work, be warned that using circular dependencies (two modules depending on each other) is generally considered bad practice. However, this is the only way I know of to achieve your intended design.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But unfortunately,I will be using the same function in a couple of files..

Comment: imports in the function are bad design, all imports should go to the top.